# import heavy excel to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, optimization, import

I am having excel sheet which contains data in something like this ex. if sheet has  "city" and  "person name" columns.So every time we need to check whether the city exists in city table(mysql) or not if not then new row will be  inserted for city in city table similarly will check for person name also if don't exists in person table(mysql) then we need to save person name in person table .
So what can be the best way to import heavy excel file of  2gb atleast into mysql using php in the above explained scenario so that less queries will be executed with  less load on server and execution will be done in fraction of seconds.
Kindly suggest me the optimize solution for above scenario.

Comment: What have you looked at? There is so many ways to approach this you need to start and see where you get the issue it's not possible for someone to offer a complete solution

Comment: Dont see why you don't import jus once

Comment: Hi Mike , can you please provide me only one better approach which can do this with less queries and fast execution @MikeMiller

Comment: Hi Dagon, importing once is not an issue i want the script to be executed in less time with less queries columns of each row in excel will firstly checked into table whether its exists or not if not then only new record will be inserted every column is associated to different table.So what will be the optimize solution for this.Me initially not interested in using set_time_limit(0) for scripts. @Dagon

Comment: You can churn your sheet in manageable chunks and build up an SQL string of inserts (ie using format `...VALUES(val,val,val),(val,val,val),...`) and then fire that off once when you have completed processing the chunk

Comment: What script?  You have yet to show any code

Comment: miller thanks for showing interest in my problem .I already knew that process but currently looking something different.Anything without splitting main file into many subfiles or without creating sql files of sql statements. @MikeMiller

Comment: Dagon its simple script of php to read excel file and to import the records into database.There is nothing to show any code .I just need the logic to write an optimize code to make it work with perfection and faster .@Dagon

Comment: Ultimately you are probably going to have to chunk it up. You dont need to split into many files though the chunking can be done by some array splitting and some offsets and you dont need to create a file for the sql you just need to build up a single statement and run it at the end. there is no other way to reduce the number of statements run

Comment: Also as @Dagon says you should come here with code to support this is just a theoretical question and too vague to get any real support here. You could try on 'Programmers' i think it is better for this kind of discursive theory

Comment: if i will create sql file of statement there will be no chances of breakdown it will be executed using linux command in php bcoz running sql command in browser can be a tedious task or chances of breakdown possiblity.Anyway thanks for support miller i need to create chunks either of file or in form of arrays. If you have any other solution apart from this kindly share with me i will be really grateful to you.@MikeMiller

Comment: @Dagon can you please tell me about 'Programmers' .can you please provide me the link i would like to visit there it will be good for me if i get some other solution.

Comment: Show your source code, and part of the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Please **don't cross-post to Programmers like [you did](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/286918/40065)**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i am sorry basile i will not do this again.Excel sheet which i contains having 65k records and when i do simply import using simple process it takes 45 minutes to import it checks each and every column of every row whether its exists or not in database if not then inser operation took place.Any suggestion apart from doing chunk of file.

Comment: How often are you running this script? It sounds like you might spend more time trying to optimize it than you will waiting for it to run.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod  It dont depends upon me whenever client wishes to upload excel he will do and my code will just import it into database .Yes i am giving time on optimization

Answer (score 0):

For high speed ingestion that needs to "normalize" the data as it goes, do it in two steps (after loading the raw data into a temp table):

First, add the new values (of `host_name` in this example):

```
# This should not be in the main transaction, and it shoud be with autocommit = ON
# In fact, it could lead to strange errors if this were part of the main transaction and it ROLLBACKed.
INSERT IGNORE INTO HostNorm (host_name)
    SELECT DISTINCT s.host_name
        FROM Staging AS s
        LEFT JOIN HostNorm AS n  ON n.host_name = s.host_name
        WHERE n.host_id IS NULL;
```

Then grab the `host_id` for putting into the Fact table:

```
# Also not in the main transaction, and it should be with autocommit = ON
# This multi-table UPDATE sets the ids in Staging:
UPDATE   HostNorm AS n
    JOIN Staging AS s  ON s.host_name = n host_name
    SET s.host_id = n.host_id
```

[More discussion in my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table)